# How to make a drawing canvas responsive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

I have a drawable canvas. The problem is, whenever you're resizing, the content inside canvas is getting cut out.

Meaning, if I would draw something in the middle, then resize to the half of the width, then that drawing would mostly be gone.

```
_________________       _________
|                |      |        | 
|     o   o      |      |     o  |
|       o        |  >>  |       o|     
|     -----      |      |     ---|
|________________|      |________|
```

The result I want:

```
________      ____________
|       |     |   o   o   |
| o   o |     |     o     |
|   o   | OR  |___-----___|
|  ---  |     
|_______|
```

This is how my Canvas is built:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" [width]="canvasWidth" [height]="canvasHeight"></canvas>
```

Hostlistener for resizing:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) onResize(e) {

    this.canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

    //Bad solution, but redrawing the canvas after the painting disappears due resizing.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0);
    }, 1);
  }


 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  }
```

Any idea of how to make the canvas/painting responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `swidth`, `sheight`, `dwidth`, and `dheight` properties of the [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function to scale the canvas image without changing it. The `s`-prefixed params refer to the original image and the `d`-prefixed params refer to the new image. Also, (in my experience) when specifying these properties you also need to specify the other optional params so it knows where to start capturing/drawing the image.

This should be what you need because resizing the canvas could also be thought of as scaling the image.

**For example, to re-draw the image at the origin whose size was originally `originalWidth` X `originalHeight` to be `newWidth` X `newHeight`:**

```
this.ctx.drawImage(this.canvas,
                   0, // sx, set this if the original image is offset from the origin
                   0, // sy, set this if the original image is offset from the origin
                   originalWidth, 
                   originalHeight,
                   0, // dx, set this if you want the image to be offset from the origin
                   0, // dy, set this if you want the image to be offset from the origin
                   newWidth, 
                   newHeight);
```

Note: You might also need to change your capture method to ensure the original image isn't lost after the canvas resize. You shouldn't have to worry about this if your original method worked, but I figured I'd add it for completeness.